# Classify $\mathbb{Z}_{108}$ up to an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

**Note:** My question is a lot more general. Can you provide me with an answer about what "classify" implies when it comes to groups and what are the steps that one should follow to carry through with this process?

---

**Attempt:**

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{108}$

According to the [Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian groups](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-fundamental-theorem-of-finite-abelian-groups), if we write $G$'s order as
$$
108=2^23^3
$$
we can infer that $G$ is isomorphic to one of the following direct products of cyclic groups:

\begin{align*}
1.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}_{27} \\
2.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times\mathbb{Z}_9 \\
3.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_{27} \\
4.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \\
5.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times\mathbb{Z}_9 \\
6.&\quad \mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \\
\end{align*}
Does this process go any further or after this observation $G$ is considered as classified?

Comment: Are you trying to classify abelian groups of order 108?

Comment: @the_fox Just $\mathbb{Z}_{108}$. I'm currently studying about this theorem I mentioned and I've encountered many questions/problems similar to this one. I want to know what "classifying up to an isomorphism" means and how is it done for this example.

Comment: You can just use the Chinese remainder theorem and you see that $\mathbb{Z}/108\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense (to me) to ask for a classification up to isomorphism of a concrete, specific group. When a classification (up to isomorphism) of all groups with a specific property is asked for, what usually happens is that you need to provide a list of concrete groups which exhausts that list in that any group with the property is isomorphic to a group in the list. So the list you have provided is a classification of all abelian groups of order $108$.

Comment: To see that your group is isomorphic to one in the list all you need is the theorem that $C_n \times C_m \cong C_{nm}$ when $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

Comment: @the_fox Thanks! This is a theorem I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct. However, you are not yet finished! You still need to show which of these direct products actually represents $G$, since those products aren't all isomorhpic to each other. Consider the order of each element of $G$. If you find one with, say, order 27, then $G$ is isomorphic to either $1.$ or $3.$ in your list. Next, you can try to find an element with order 2. If you find one, you are done, and the result is $3.$ . If you instead find an element with order 4, then $G$ is isomorphic to $1.$ .

Comment: $4$ has order $27$, but $54$ has order $2$ and $27$ has order $4$, so I'm a bit confused now. Is it 1. or 3. ?

Comment: 54 is contained within the cyclic subgroup generated by 27.